# How to detect collision force?

Tags: cocos2d-x

Is there any way in cocos2d-x to detect collision force? I would like to make a different sound effects depending on collision force or disable sound effect at all in some cases.

For example: when I perform scaleTo action on my sprite that is lying on the ground, it starts changing it's size every moment and so it hits the ground every moment too. On every hit the application plays sound effect. I would like to play it only when my sprite falls from some real height.

Answer (score 0):

Do you detect the collision in some update() function, isn't it? So, you need to remember object position on previous update() call. Something like this:

```
Vec2 previousPosition;

void YourClass::update(float dt)
{
    …
    this->detectCollision();
    this->updatePhysics();
    this->makeSomethingElse();
    …
}

void YourClass::detectCollision()
{
    currentPosition = yourObject->getPosition();
    float distance = currentPosition.getDistance(previousPosition)
    if (obstacleRect.intersectsRect(yourObjectRect))
    {
        // collide handler 
        if (distance == 0)
            // do nothing
        if (distance > threshold)
            // play some sound
    }
    …
    previousPosition = currentPosition;
    …
}
```

Depends of distance between current and previous object location you can calculate object’s speed and estimate it force.
In your example, when object collides through ScaleTo, its position is stable, and distance and speed = 0.
If you move the object and the obstacle, the calculation of speed is more complicated and must be carried out according to the [rules of vector addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction)

Comment: Thank you! But I believe it's really more complex then you described. What about 2 objects with different mass, having different velocity vector. How can I calculate the force when they collide?

Comment: Of course, if you have physics bodies is better to calculate impulse (velocity or distance from my example multiplied by the mass), not distance. And if the obstacle moves also, you need to add the vectors. But the basic principle is the same.